# How to persist a class using hibernate which is used in many different ways?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am new to hibernate world, still learning it. I am trying to persist one class in database using hibernate. Objects of this class can have different meaning in its client classes. Following is the class definition which I want to persist :

```
class Entity {
    int id;
    String name;
}

class ClientClass {
    int clientClassID;
    List<Entity> employerList;
    List<Entity> clientList;
}
```

Mapping file for `ClientClass` is as follows :

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.foo.bar.model">
    <class name="ClientClass" table="CLIENTS">
        <id name="clientClassID" column="CLIENT_ID" type="integer"
            unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <set name="clientList" table="PROJECT_CLIENTS" cascade="all">
            <key column="CLIENT_ID" />
            <many-to-many column="CLIENT_ID" class="Entity" />
        </set>
        <property name="description" type="string" length="1000" />
        <set name="employerList" table="PROJECT_EMPLOYERS" cascade="all">
            <key column="CLIENT_ID" />
            <many-to-many column="EMPLOYER_ID" class="Entity" />
        </set>
         </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am not able to understand how to write mappings for `Entity` class? 
Please help me. If you need more details then please let me know.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to map `Entity` as own class first.

```
<class name="Entity" table="ENTITY">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="integer"
        unsaved-value="0">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string" />
</class>
```

Then you can add it as Many-To-Many association in your other classes. I do not really understand how your mapping on `EMPLOYER_NAME` and `CLIENT_ID` should work.

For further documentation see: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-ofvalues

Comment: thanks a lot for answer. If I do not want to create ENTITY table, then what should I do? Instead of ENTITY class, I want to create tables named CLIENT_LIST or EMPLOYER_LIST which have id and name columns.

Comment: Is it still many-to-many then? I think it is one-to-many but that's not the solution. I would create two further classes that extend `Entity` and map them. There is no possibility to map one entity on two tables.

Comment: okay, but then I have to create those subclasses unnecessarily just because hibernate cant do this. Actually earlier I had created different database schema but I was facing some problem in it. So I changed it to the one like above. I have posted question on SO. Here is the link for it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964417/unable-to-generate-tables-using-hibernate . Please have a look at it.